# Can a "metargem" fulfill the Targum obligation of "2 Mikra and 1 Targum"?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, torah-service

I understand that Yemenite congregations still use a *metargem* - a person who translates each Torah verse being read into Targum Onkelos. (The *metargem* was much more common centuries ago.)

[O.C. 585:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=127) says that one can fulfill one of the *mikrah* obligations by reading together with the Torah reader during the Shabbat Torah service. (See *Mishnah Berurah* note #14 for dissenting opinions.)

Can the *metargem* ,assuming that he has already done the 2 Mikrah part (see a previous par. in the same chapter of O.C. that says that one must already complete the 2 *mikrah* before doing Targum.) similarly, fulfill the *targum* obligation at that time?

Comment: Do you mean a congregant reading along? It never says the Torah reader fulfills while reading in the Torah. Just that someone can read along.

Comment: Why would you think he can't? Doesn't the Shulchan Arukh you cite even explicitly say so "One can fulfill the obligation of 2 Mikra + 1 Targum during the Torah reading time"?

Comment: @DoubleAA "It never says the Torah reader fulfills while reading in the Torah". Indeed, it does not. But, since the reader is reading for the congregation, he is actually doing *Mikrah*. It seems obvious that he would be fulfilling that obligation via his own reading, already. I have to reread O.C. to address your 2nd question.